# ngOnInit not called when coming back

Tags: angular, ionic2

I noticed that the `ngOnInit()` method gets not called when I come back to the page which is already instanced. I have to use any other method for this? I need a method which is called everytime when he is visiting the specific page.

**EDIT**
Tested already `onPageWillEnter()` but it gets not fired in Ionic 2

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check [Lifecycle Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/) section in the link.

You can use ionic 2 lifecycle hook

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
 //your methods
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you change a route so that only a parameter value changed, then the component is reused.

You can use

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.params.subscribe(val => myInit());
}
```

to call your initialization code instead of using `ngOnInit()` in such cases.

Answer (score 4):

To recall ngOnInit everytime when page is visiting, you should use ngOnDestroy. For example, if your component content depends on code in url, you should use OnDestroy, in this way:

```
export class GRMTasksComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

   subParams: Subscription;

   ngOnInit() {
        this.subParams = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
           //some code...
      });
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subParams.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular components have life cycle methods, once a component a loaded, it will call ngOnInit() method and then in order to properly close it, we need to emit close event **this.onClose.emit()**, so when the component called 2nd time, it will trigger ngOnInit() again.

Example: close is a custom method where we call onClose event.

```
close(): void
{
 // do some custom logic here...
 this.onClose.emit();
}
```

But make sure your component class implements OnInit.