# Angular 6 ngOnInit not firing when clicking browser's back button

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm having problems with routes that involve parameters. When I try to go back with the browser's back button the ngoninit of the previous component doesn't fire.

Steps to reproduce the error with the angular's tutorial:

- Download the tutorial from https://angular.io/tutorial and run `npm install`
- Build the app with the command `ng build --prod --build-optimizer` or `ng build --prod`
- Upload the static files generated by the previous step to an nginx or apache server with the respective configuration file having the recomended lines of code in angular docs. https://angular.io/guide/deployment
- Click one of the top heros in the dashboard.
- Click browser's back button.

By following those steps you will see the top heros are not loaded in the dashboard which is exactly the same problem I'm having with my app. This is be cause ngOnInit is not called when going back specifically with the back button.

A few things to note:
This problem only occurs while using Firefox, Chrome or Opera.
This problem doesn't accurs while using development mode `ng serve`.
I updated to angular 7 and still have the same issue.

Is there any way I could solve this problem? I didn't find anything about this in angular's repo issues.

Comment: Is this an `ngOnInit` for a component/route/view that utilizes `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: If the route params haven't changed, then `ngOnInit()` may not fire. This has been solved by using [constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42388235/5059657) instead. Also people have use popState() using [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location)

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky The component that is reading the parameter has the `ActivatedRoute` but the previous component is the one where the ngOnInit is not called. It is exactly like this [example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt6/stackblitz.html)

Comment: From which component to which going back `ngOnInit()` is not fired? Can it be that you are going back from one child to another child, but expect `ngOnInit()` from parent component? If it is the case, then your parent component is not getting destroyed, then it will not be initialized. Same is true for other components. Make sure that it is getting destroyed with `ngOnDestroy()` to expect `ngOnInit()`. You may use `Augury` chrome extension which helps to see the relations between the components.

Comment: @muradm I'm going back to a sibling component like the angular's tutorial shows. It is pretty weird no one says anything about this since it looks to be working incorrectly even in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You should tru something like this:

```
this._router.events.subscribe(event => {
    // ... yourcode
});
```

Comment: Hi, I haven't had the change to try this but I want to tell you that I put this problem into the issues in the Angular's github and they just close it without trying the steps I told them to try. Also i want to say that in my case the "solution" was not using a subdomain. This only happens when you deploy to a subdomain and apparently also when you use apache or nginx. More info: [Angular's Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26829)